# active state and city display only in django template ForeignKey

Tags: django, model

I have country state city model and here is my view

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" %(self.name)

class State(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" %(self.name)

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    state = models.ForeignKey(State, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" %(self.name)
```

here is my view

```
class CountryList(ListView):
    def get_template_names(self, *args, **kwargs):
      return ['albums/list.html']
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
      return Country.objects.all()
```

now i want to show country with active state and active cities only how can do this in my template ?

my view

```
{% for x in object_list %}
    {{x.name}} : <br>
    {% for state in x.state_set.all %}
        {{ state.name }} >>
        {%for city in state.city_set.all %}
            ------#
            {{ city.name }}
        {% endfor %}    
        <br>
    {% endfor %}
    </br>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: For this purpose you can use [model managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers-and-model-inheritance) and limit queryset in it.

Comment: Filtering will be similar to this (here I use original manager): ```Country.objects.filter(state_set__is_active=True)``` for State checkout.

Comment: Do you need to do this in another view? You say "how can I do this in my template" but it should be the view that passes the correct list. If all you want is to limit the countries, then don't `return Country.objects.all()` but the filtered queryset.

Comment: how can i do this ? i want to implement city and state is active  = True

Comment: @dirkgroten how can i implement city and state is_active in my query set please suggest me, I have implement state__is_active = True but i implement city__is_active = True it is not working

Comment: `Country.objects.filter(state__is_active=True, state__city__is_active=True)`: this will filter countries that have states that are both active themselves **and** have cities that are active.

Comment: If you want countries that have active states **and** countries that have active cities (not the same as above if there are active cities with inactive states), then `Countries.objects.filter(state__is_active=True).filter(state__city__is_active=True)`.

Comment: it is working but dear data is repeated so many time :(

Comment: i updated my view in question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205885/discussion-between-jaskaran-singh-rajal-and-dirkgroten).